# Changing variable values in GUI Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I wrote a game with a lot of classes,and it works fine.But it is too exhausting to change the values of the variables from source code every time I want to test something.So I researched how can I enter the values of the variable without using window.The behaviour I want is that when I run the program a panel will be openned and it will ask me the values of variables.I tried to use JInternal frame,eclipse creates a default JInternal Frame for you.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
public class Test extends JInternalFrame {
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BoardConstructor frame = new BoardConstructor();
                    frame.setTitle("Monopoly");
                    frame.setSize(1500,750);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(new MyShape());
                    Test frame1 = new Test();
                    frame1.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Test() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
}}
```

I wrote my main function into this which simply creates my game.Now what I think should work is that this class should access the variables in other classes and change them but I have no idea how it works in reality.How can I accomplish that?

Comment: you could use a `JDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try live debugging in Eclipse than if you have a pause feature, you can easily change the variable values in the code. If that's not what you're looking for let me know